# How would I load different slides on a page depending on which link the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to [create a site like this](http://www.gogl-architekten.at/) on WordPress where you have multiple slides (the navigation on top call the different slides) that fade in/out based on which link is clicked by the user. I'm looking for some input as to how I should go about it in an efficient way. Would I be calling these separate slides through Ajax? Should I just preload all of the images together and include them all in one html file? Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how to code better. I'm not asking you to code for me. I just need to know how I should go about doing this so I can take the time to learn the proper skills. Why the down votes?

Comment: I'm going to guess the downvotes are because this is not a very specific question about code. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: `Would I be calling these separate slides through Ajax? Should I just preload all of the images together and include them all in one html file?` This is very subjective. Do what you feel suits your situation. It's better to do it with AJAX if there's a lot of images or if they're huge. Otherwise it's fine to have them pre-loaded. What you're looking for is a carousel widget and I've found that [this one](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is great for almost all situations.

Comment: @Alternatex Thanks for the tip on the carousel. I like that it's adaptable to a lot of different situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some questions you need to ask yourself that may impact the best way to do things.

How fast are slides going to be navigated? How "big" are the slides data-wise. How many slides are there?

If there are many, large slides it would probably be in your best interest to lazy load some of the later content.

If there are few, small slides the opposite might be true.